# Water-Soluble Photoinitiators for Free-Radical Photopolymerizations?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Could anyone recommend me a good proven free-radical photoinitiator available commercially suitable for (meth)acrylate-based UV-light photo-polymerizations ocurring in water phase, preferably with high water solubility and moderate-to-high quantum yield of photoinitiation? Commercial suppliers would also be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most azo-based water-soluble thermal initiators can also be excited by UV light and therefore used as a photoinitiator in radical polymerizations, for example, V-50 and V-501. They are inexpensive and available from many commercial sources but they do not usually have very high quantum yield. Depending on your specific application scenario, you can also choose phenone-based water-soluble initiators, such as 2-hydroxy-4′-(2-hydroxyethoxy)-2-methylpropiophenone, which has a higher quantum yield.